# How to sum every second column depending on the first column value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Team,

This is driving me mad.

I know how to sum every second column in a row: ie {=SUM(A1:G1*(MOD(COLUMN(A1:G1),2)=0))}

What I need to know is how to sum all of the first columns unless there is a value in the second column at which point use the second column. ie =SUM(IF(B1="",A1,B1))

But I need to do this over a decent range.

Just a bit of back ground I have multiple rows of 
'Forecast Week1, Actual Week1, Forecast Week2, Actual Week2............'

I need to sum the entire row using 'actual' values where available else use 'forecast' values

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: A screenshot of your spreadsheet layout with sample data would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is check if the column is even OR if the NEXT column is populated.  By this version of the logic will also include blank even columns, but that won't effect your total.

So we'll want to use two different arrays, one offset by one, so I'm adding B1:H1, which means you'll have to leave a blank column H1, this way during each cells calculation we can be considering its value and the value of the next cell.

What you want to do is this, but this WILL NOT WORK

```
{=SUM(A1:G1*OR(B1:H1="",MOD(COLUMN(A1:G1),2)=0)}
```

The reason the above doesn't work is because the OR won't preserve the array, and will yield a single TRUE/FALSE value even within an array function like you're using.

So we're going to do an algebric OR which is (1-(1-CONDITION1)*(1-CONDITION2)).  This works because TRUE is a 1 and FALSE is a 0, as you're already taking advantage of, the multiplication is an AND, but by saying NOT (Not Condition1 AND Not Condition2) it is the equivalent of Condition1 OR Condition2.  If that doesn't makes sense try going through all 4 possibilities of True/False combinations.

So we're finally left with:

```
{=SUM(A1:G1*(1-(1-(B1:H1=""))*(1-(MOD(COLUMN(A1:G1),2)=0))))}
```

Comment: If you don't want to add the blank row H, then you colud lower both ranges by one, A1:F1 and B1:G1, which means you're not looking to add in column G anymore, so you don't have to look at H, but you can just do a stand alone IF on column G's value to handle that very last column.

Comment: Result!!  This is some great stuff. Thank your for the help!